# Low-height rear rack for Bike Friday New World Tourist folding bike

Tags: parts, rack, folding-bicycle, bike-friday

I'm looking for a rear rack for my Bike Friday New World Tourist (20" wheels). I've come across a bunch of rear racks [like this one](https://store.bikefriday.com/product_info.php?cPath=64&products_id=719) that sit high above the wheel. But I'm searching for one that is not so high - I want a lower height rack that will not block my rear light (clamped to the seatpost) when I put my bag on top of the rear rack and that will let the weight of my bag sit lower so that I have a lower center of gravity.

Where can I find this?

Comment: The product recommendation question is off topic, but the general answer you want is "look at racks for folding bikes" because that is where you'll find small wheels.

Comment: It sounds like quite a specialised bike, I think your best option might be to contact the manufacturer

Comment: Consider finding a cheap normal rack and modify it for your needs.

Comment: @Criggie thanks for the idea, but modifying a normal rack would be almost as difficult as fabricating one from scratch. With most standard racks, there is a triangle formed by three tubes that join together near where the rack mounts on the dropout. That intersection determines the height of the rack.

Comment: @MikeEng Yes exactly.  Most racks are made of steel tubing which can be carefully bent or realigned with nothing more than a bench vice and a good hand tug   I've done it myself, converting a rack to be longer so it works as a rear mudguard/fender.  You could cut the posts short, flatten them to a tang in the vice or some judicious hammer work, drill a new hole through the fresh flat and go from there.  Check ebay or gumtree or craigslist for cheap racks - a donor one might cost you $5 used.   If you were in Christchurch, NZ I'd offer to help.

Comment: Also the Tern Cargo rear rack fits well. A very nice rack which I can highly recommend: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/65941/39705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Biologic Portage Tern](http://smile.amazon.com/BioLogic-Portage-Rear-Rack-Silver/dp/B006OSYSUA/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1449427759&sr=8-2&keywords=dahon%20rear%20rack) seems to fit the bill.

[image]

Comment: Racktime Fold It Fix: https://www.racktime.com/produkte/systemtraeger/racktime-product/foldit-fix